Pulse simulator Pennylane
I am trying to execute a pulse simulator with Pennylane. I saw on the Internet this tutorial so I tried to run it, but it takes too long (it was running for 180 minutes when I gave up and aborted it :O).
Just to check, I tried to make a simpler program instead. Here it is the code:
import pennylane as qml
import jax.numpy as jnp
import jax

    
jax.config.update("jax_enable_x64", True)

wire = 0
dev = qml.device("default.mixed", wires=[wire])

qubit_freq = 31179405260.046936 # Hz

H0 = qml.pulse.transmon_interaction(
    qubit_freq=[qubit_freq], connections=[], coupling=[], wires=[wire]
)
Hd0 = qml.pulse.transmon_drive(
    amplitude=qml.pulse.constant,
    phase=qml.pulse.constant,
    freq=qubit_freq,
    wires=[wire],
)


@qml.qnode(dev, interface='jax')
def circuit(params, duration):
    qml.evolve(H0 + Hd0)(params, t=duration)
    return qml.expval(qml.PauliZ(wire))

phi0 = 0.0
amp0 = 0.3

params = jnp.array([amp0, phi0])
t = jnp.linspace(0, 10, 3)
z = jax.vmap(circuit, (None, 0))(params, t)


plt.plot(t, z, "x-")
plt.legend()
plt.ylabel("<Z>")
plt.xlabel("t1")

Surprisingly, this simple program, that only need to compute the evolution at three timesteps, takes as well too long (at least 30 minutes, I gave up).
Could, please, any of you try to run it in your computers to check if it is a matter of my computer or if it is normal? In the latter, do you know any alternative for pulse simulating? I have already tried pulse module inside qiskit but I did not like it much since its documentation is not updated for version 1.0, so I am looking for alternatives.
Here are my needs: I want to calibrate quantum gates and execute it manually as pulses, in an ideal case and in noisy simulations. I will not require to execute it in many qubits (at most 5 I think), in case that is helpful.
Thanks in advance!
PS: in case it helps, my computer does not have a dedicated GPU.

You are currently trying to simulate 10 * 31179405260 rotations, that will take a while indeed :) Did you perhaps mean to simulate a transmon qubit with frequency 31 Ghz for 10 ns? Then this should do and run in no time:
import pennylane as qml
import jax.numpy as jnp
import jax

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    
jax.config.update("jax_enable_x64", True)

wire = 0
dev = qml.device("default.mixed", wires=[wire])

qubit_freq = 31.179405260046936 # GHz

H0 = qml.pulse.transmon_interaction(
    qubit_freq=[qubit_freq], connections=[], coupling=[], wires=[wire]
)
Hd0 = qml.pulse.transmon_drive(
    amplitude=qml.pulse.constant,
    phase=qml.pulse.constant,
    freq=qubit_freq,
    wires=[wire],
)


@qml.qnode(dev, interface='jax')
def circuit(params, duration):
    qml.evolve(H0 + Hd0)(params, t=duration)
    return qml.expval(qml.PauliZ(wire))

phi0 = 0.0
amp0 = 0.3

params = jnp.array([amp0, phi0])
t = jnp.linspace(0, 10, 3)
z = jax.vmap(circuit, (None, 0))(params, t)


plt.plot(t, z, "x-")
plt.legend()
plt.ylabel("<Z>")
plt.xlabel("t1")

I would also recommend to use qml.device("default.qubit") instead of the mixed device.
Note also that under the hood qml.evolve is using an adaptive-stepsize ODE solver (see, e.g. Runge Kutta). So even though you provide just 3 times, there are many more evaluations under the hood (in your example maaaaany many more ;)). In a nutshell, these solvers have two estimates of different order for the next time step of the evolution. And it is adjusting the stepsize such that a certain error threshold between the higher and lower order step is reached. So to simulate 3000000000 rotations, it will take O(3000000000) evaluations.
The functionality to provide a multitude of steps is mainly to a) "guide" the evolution and b) obtain intermediate values with qml.evolve(H)(params, t, return_intermediate=True)

Thank you so much! Yes, like this it work perfectly. Just to be sure, as for as the code is concerned, it was mainly because the frequency is actually expressed in GHz and not in Hz as I thought, right?

Yes! The hardware device may expect SI units, but in simulation you are trying to avoid very large and very small numbers. In particular for pulse stuff, you want to express frequencies and times in the same, opposing, order of magnitude, e.g. GHz (10^9) and ns (10^-9), or for MHz (10^6) and μs (10^-6) - which in the exponent "cancel" each other.

great! Thanks again!


it was mainly because the frequency is actually expressed in GHz and not in Hz as I thought, right?

Exactly - by using GHz and nanoseconds instead of Hz and seconds, the units work out the same, but very large and very small numbers are harder for the solver to handle. It seems like you were already using nanoseconds, so you just needed to update your frequency to GHz for everything to work out :)
If you will be doing optimization (so calling the QNode many times with different parameters), I would also suggest jitting your QNode. It will slow the very first execution down a bit, but make all future calls to the QNode faster. It probably won’t matter much for the small problem you posted here, since this runs very quickly, but if you want to add several qubits and perform an optimization, it might speed things up for you. You can just do:
@jax.jit
@qml.qnode(dev, interface='jax')
def circuit(params, duration):
    qml.evolve(H0 + Hd0)(params, t=duration)
    return qml.expval(qml.PauliZ(wire))

In terms of your final point about ideally planning to also run this with a noisy simulation, what kind of noise are you hoping to apply?

Hello! Thanks for your reply. That's a very nice tip, what I am actually planing to do involves hundreds of evaluations :) As for the noise, I need to check, but I saw that in Pennylane there are several types of noise, so it is kind of solved (I am just looking for alternatives to qiskit, I think I found it :D ) Thanks again
